# Click an image in html

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to click on this image. Here is the source code of the html:

When invisible

```
<div id="da8b" style="display:none;height:68px;" onclick="clr('8');ul=0"><div id="da8d" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#ccc;width:190px;height:68px;vertical-align:middle">Click the red dot</div><span id="da8c" style="position:absolute;z-index:9"><a href="http://www.neobux.com/v/?a=l&amp;l=F9D1D4EBFDE9FA5FFF9AD141BE59741DAD9DA5CO879B63A65EB7O4EE8COF1944556BOCEFDDC552F14C4OD9F2C7FD16EF28C932E4E25A7A6F16AA6CEFO87C825A" id="l8" target="_blank" onkeydown="return false;" tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur()" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="if((ul*1)<10) jQuery.ajax({url: '/v/h/'});"><img src="http://cache1.neodevlda.netdna-cdn.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif" style="z-index:-99" width="16" height="16" border="0" id="i8" onclick="gg[8]=1;img0('8');"></a></span></div>
```

When visible

```
<div id="da8b" style="display: block; height: 68px;" onclick="clr('8');ul=0"><div id="da8d" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#ccc;width:190px;height:68px;vertical-align:middle">Click the red dot</div><span id="da8c" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9; padding-left: 18px;"><a href="http://www.neobux.com/v/?a=l&amp;l=F9D1D4EBFDE9FA5FFF9AD141BE59741DAD9DA5C0879B63A65EB704EE8C0F1944556B0CEFDDC552F14C40D9F2C7FD16EF28CD32E4E25A7A6F16AA6CEF087C825A&amp;vl=D918A1F8F01E009A39C51B7962C0C1576FEE81B49E07CEEA7F1993FFD5FBB50D2418BDE61E7CDFC4F16708B4F16A5FFDE7F7A7D8A885896B" id="l8" target="_blank" onkeydown="return false;" tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur()" oncontextmenu="return false;" onclick="if((ul*1)<10) jQuery.ajax({url: '/v/h/'});"><img src="http://cache1.neodevlda.netdna-cdn.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif" style="z-index: -99; margin-top: 19px;" width="16" height="16" border="0" id="i8" onclick="gg[8]=1;img0('8');"></a></span></div>
```

The above code is from the website directly. I don't know what functions to use in c#.

I need it to click on this part of the html

```
<img src="http://cache1.neodevlda.netdna-cdn.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif" style="z-index:-99" width="16" height="16" border="0" id="i8" onclick="gg[8]=1;img0('8');"></a>
```

I want it to click on the `src =` part when it is visible because in this website the ID changes every time. Same with the `onclick` it changes every time. but `src` stays the same.

*NOTE the id always has "i" in front it just has a different number at the end of it every time*

I have no idea how to do this in c# so i don't even know where to start.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The src will be the location of the image to display.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want it to click on the src when it is visible.

Comment: 1) `click on the src` doesn't make sense.  You can click on an anchor tag (`<a>`) but not on an attribute of `img`.  2)  What doesn't your aspx file look like for defining the image.

Comment: Please look at the above source codes again i put the one for both visible and invisible

Answer (score 0):

"I want it to click on the src" means to me:

```html
Click this -
<a href="http://cache1.neodevlda.netdna-cdn.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif">
  <img src="http://cache1.neodevlda.netdna-cdn.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif" style="z-index:-99" width="16" height="16" border="0" id="i8">
</a>
<br />or

<br/>Click this -

<img src="http://cache1.neodevlda.netdna-cdn.com/imagens/badge_a1.gif" onclick="window.open(this.src, '_self', '');" style="cursor: pointer;">
```